# transponer todas las matrices de una lista y guardarlas en otra lista en Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo distintas listas de matrices en un programa de Rstudio, la cantidad de elementos guardados en cada una de estas listas puede llegar a ser un numero grande por lo que busco algun modo de que transponga cada una de las matrices y las guarde en otra lista, una forma de hacerlo es

```
'ltrasp=t(lista[[1]]),t(lista[[2]]),...t(lista[[n]])'
```

La idea es hacerlo si se puede de una forma iterativa para cada uno de los elementos de la lista sin hacerlo uno por uno y que se almacenen en otra lista distinta

la otra duda es como multiplicar cada uno de los elementos de una lista por cada uno de los elementos de otra lista y guardarla tambien en otra lista
, es decir

```
'LMult=listaA[[1]]*listaB[[1]],listaA[[2]]*listaB[[2]],...listaA[[n]]*listaB[[n]]
```

y asi sucesivamente guardadando cada una de las multiplicaciones en una lista aparte.

Comment: Hola @Miguel Padilla, sólo quiero acotar que las matrices tienen que tener las mismas dimensiones de filas y columnas (`dim(M)[1]==dim(M)[2] # TRUE`) para que sean multiplicadas `LMult=listaA[[1]]*listaB[[1]],...` porque de lo contrario se obtendrá error `M<-matrix(1:12, nrow=3); M*t(M); Error in M * t(M) : non-conformable arrays`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pongamos el caso de una lista como la siguiente:

```
v <- 1:27
lmat <- lapply(split(v, ceiling(seq_along(v)/9)), FUN=function(x) matrix(x, nrow=3))
lmat

$`1`
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9

$`2`
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   10   13   16
[2,]   11   14   17
[3,]   12   15   18

$`3`
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   19   22   25
[2,]   20   23   26
[3,]   21   24   27
```

La forma básica de transponer cada matriz de la lista, sería usar un **ciclo explícito**:

```
ltrasp <- list()
for(i in seq(lmat)) {
    ltrasp[[i]] <- t(lmat[[i]])
}
```

Sin embargo, R ofrece la posibilidad de los **ciclos implícitos**, hablo de las familia de funciones `*apply()`, aunque no necesariamente sea una solución más performante, simplifica mucho el código. En este ejemplo podemos usar `lapply()` que "aplica" una función a todos los elementos de una lista y retorna otra lista:

```
lapply(lmat, t)
```

En cuanto a multiplicar dos listas, puedes usar  los mismos mecanismos comentados, pero en vez de iterar directamente sobre los elementos, deberías hacerlos sobre el índice de estos, por ejemplo:

```
lapply(seq(lmat), FUN=function(x) lmat[[x]] * lmat[[x]])
```

Comment: ¿en la última línea no sería `lapply(seq(lmat), FUN=function(x) lmat[[x]] * t(lmat[[x]]))`? Alternativamente con `purrr::` se podría  usar `map2` para iterar sobre dos listas:, la original y una de matrices transpuestas  `lmat %>% map2(., map(., t), ~.x*.y)`.

Comment: @mpaladino, la segunda consulta del OP, la interprete no relacionada con la primer, por lo que es un simple ejemplo. Pensé introducir `map` a la respuesta, pero el problema es tan simple que por ahí confunde. De todas formas, sin duda estoy de acuerdo contigo que  `map()` es super recomendable.

Comment: tenés razón, eran dos preguntas en una. Saludos!